# Can we send attachement with nagios mail alert?

Tags: nagios

I need to send Nagios status of service/host email alert with attachment like .txt, .doc, .jpg kind of files. How can i achieve this, anyone please help to this.

Thanks & Regards,
Prabakaran.R

Answer (score 0):

By default, Nagios uses the mail command to send notifications like below, you could switch to something like mutt to add attachments.

[More info on Mutt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/sending-mail-with-attachment.html)

```
define command{
    command_name    notify-host-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type:     $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```